# Zigbee CC2531 USB Dongle and Intruder Alarm System

Tags: zigbee

I have a problem with my CC2531 USB Dongle. I use it as a Zigbee coordinator. I can see all the devices inside my PAN, but IAS zones are not communicating with it. When I change the state of contact switch, or Motion sensor, I don't get data in my gateway app. But, I have IAS remote controller, and in my gateway application i get data on TCP port when i click remote controller button. I read something about Enrollment function on coordinator, but I don't really understand what it means. I guess that problem is that I don't have IAS CIE and I need my CC2531 to act like one.

Does anyone have idea what to do? Do I need to flash other firmware or change something in config files. I am quite new in this so I don't really know what is important, so if you need some additional info please ask.

Comment: This is a programming forum; it appears you are looking for support with existing software which you didn't write yourself.

Comment: Where to ask then. Zigbee is technology that many programmers use. So I tried to find help here. Sorry if you see this as spam.

Comment: Well, we don't see it as spam, we just think it should have been asked over at SuperUser (the sister site for problems with existing software). If it was spam, it doesn't belong at any of the StackExchange sites. (Well, Cooking might accept questions about the old-fashioned type of spam ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAS Devices work slightly differently than other Zigbee devices in that they are "locked" to a CIE node.  This basically means that commissioning IAS devices requires the following steps

1. Write your USB dongle's IEEE/MAC address to the IAS CIE attribute on the device
2. If the device is "trip to pair", trip the sensor and it will send in a ZoneEnrollRequest message, to which you respond with a ZoneEnrollResponse with a status of SUCCESS

If the device does not require "trip to pair", you can just directly send a ZoneEnrollResponse message after writing the IAS CIE attribute.

Out of curiosity, which brand of sensors are you testing with?

Comment: Thank you very much...We use Heiman sensors...http://www.heimantech.com/products_list/&pmcId=54.html. But please can you help me. How will I write attribute to the device. Is it enough to change zcl.xml or I need to do Html request with command id  to gateway subsystem??